# Firebase endAt() not working with date string?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Pretty basic question in here

My Stored Date String is like this in Firebase DB

```
23-Oct-2016 07:00:11 AM
```

Now i am firing this query , i am getting all the data starting with that date

```
   Query query = mDatabase.orderByChild("time").startAt("23-Oct-2016")
```

Now I also want to filter by current AM/PM time i am trying query like this but it has no effect on results.

Basically it should not return any object  if the current time is PM , i don't know why its not working .

```
   Query query = mDatabase.orderByChild("time").startAt("23-Oct-2016").endAt("PM");
```

Answer (score 4):

Storing dates and times as readable strings like you seem to be doing is guaranteed to give you a hard time. Strings are lexicographically ordered, while you typically want to treat dates as chronologically ordered. The two orders don't always match up.

The best way to store a date/time for querying is as a simple [timestamp](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/): the number of milliseconds since the UNIX epoch.

If you insist on storing the dates and times as more readable string, your better of storing them in a format that is both readable and will sort the same in both lexicographical and chronological order, such as the ISO 8601 formats: `20161023T150422`. This is the current time as I type this: October 23, 2016 3:04 PM UTC.

Comment: What I did wrong is that I considered startAt()  and endAt()  as like string prefix and string end compare stuff. I am new to firebase, I understood now that it's range. So basically passing only PM is not going to give me anything as it's not proper range. I need to filter data every 12 hours. I hope you got my point.

Comment: The structure I describe above allows you to filter the data based on many date/time ranges.