# Firebase orderByChild on startAt() and endAt() return wrong results

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am searching record from Firebase Database on the formated date rang converted in String type. I am calling filtering query on requestPlaceDate.

```
Query query = ordersDatabaseRef.limitToFirst(1000).orderByChild(ConstanceFnc.requestPlacedDate).startAt(startDate).endAt(endDate);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(orderListener);
```

[image]

Firebase return data including previous and next dates, not return specific date range data, what I am expecting from a query on `startAt() and endAt()`

Comment: May I know what is the input did you put ?

Comment: i am giving this type of input
Query query = ordersDatabaseRef.limitToFirst(1000).orderByChild("requestPlacedDate").startAt("01-Jul-2021").endAt("05-Jul-2021");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(orderListener);

Comment: I think you can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52567178/9346054

Answer (score 1):

> I am searching record from Firebase database on the formated date rang converted in String type.

You aren't getting the desired results because your `requestPlacedDate` field holds a String and not a Timestamp. When you order String elements, the order is lexicographical. I answered a similar question, so please check my answer from the following post:

- [How to order the nodes in firebase console based on key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46647150/how-to-order-the-nodes-in-firebase-console-based-on-key)

To accomplish the correct order for your results, you should change the type of your field to be Timestamp, as explained in my answer from the following post:

- [How to save the current date/time when I add new value to Firebase Realtime Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data)

Once your field will hold the Timestamp value, your Query will work perfectly fine.

Comment: I have Also tried this query with requestTimeStemp
String startTimeStemp = ConstanceFnc.dateTimeToTimeStemp(startDate, "11:59 PM");
        String endTimeStemp = ConstanceFnc.dateTimeToTimeStemp(endDate, "11:59 PM");
        Log.e("TAG","Start time stemp " + startTimeStemp);

Comment: Query query = ordersDatabaseRef.limitToFirst(1000).orderByChild("requestTimeStemp").startAt(startTimeStemp).endAt(endTimeStemp);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(orderListener);

Comment: When you are passing String values as "11:59 PM", you'll never get the correct results. If you pass `long` values, then you'll get the expected results. But only if the timestamps are also set correct in the database. Meaning it should **not** be something like "11:59 PM", it should a long, right?

Comment: I am converting it to Long then String like bellow...

String startTimeStemp = ConstanceFnc.dateTimeToTimeStemp(startDate, "11:59 PM");
here 
startTimeStemp
is the long value in casted in string

Comment: No, that's not how to do it. Your `requestTimeStemp` field should contain in the database a **long** value like **1625640973**. When you search the database, you should perform a Query that look like this: `.orderByChild("requestTimeStemp").startAt(1625640972).endAt(1625640974)`. See the first one end with 2, the seond with 4. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: i have also tried it... startAt() and endAt() not accept long it accept String, number

Comment: i have convert the requestTimeStemp into string and Querying.. it giving expected result

Comment: startAt() and endAt() also accept numbers, not only strings.

Comment: So when saying "it giving expected result", it means that you solved the issue?

Comment: Yes I have change some scenario... the issue is solved 
Thank You