# sorting by date in firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database that looks like this:

```
{
firstitem : {
"name" : "first_item_name",
"date" : "29/11/2018",
"user" : "random user",
"url" : "My Url",
"tag" : "firstitem"
},
seconditem : {
"name" : "second_item_name",
"date" : "20/11/2018"
"user" : "another user",
"url"  : "a url",
"tag"  : "seconditem" 
},  
thirditem : {
"name" : "third_item_name",
"date" : "20/11/2017"
"user" : "another user",
"url"  : "a url",
"tag"  : "thirditem"   
}
 ect....
}
```

I want to be able to have an option to sort by date, starting at the newest, and descending to the oldest. How can I achieve this?

This is my method for calling the firebase strings at the moment:

```
if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
        Log.i("Event", "Added");

        Firebase_Strings dlStrings = dataSnapshot.getValue(Firebase_Strings.class);
        p9p_strings.DOCUMENTARY_NAME.add(dlStrings.name);
        p9p_strings.DOCUMENTARY_SYNOPSIS.add(dlStrings.about);
        p9p_strings.DOCUMENTARY_URL.add(dlStrings.url);
        p9p_strings.DOCUMENTARY_UPLOADED.add(dlStrings.date);
        p9p_strings.DOCUMENTARY_TAG.add(dlStrings.tag);
```

Comment: Your dates are not in a very good format for sorting.  Consider storing an integer timestamp instead of a formatted string.

Comment: take all data into arraylist then used Collection sort that provide Comparator

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41552884/firebase-sort-by-points-depending-on-date/41553469#41553469, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52921518/why-doesnt-the-firebase-query-look-like-list/52931580#52931580, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216858/firebase-query-by-date-string/38226376#38226376

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way in which you can sort your items by date if you are storing the date as String `"29/11/2018"` and not as a timestamp.

To solve this, you should change the type of your `date` property to number.

And **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data)** you can how to add and get back the timestamp.

Comment: note that if you're storing your date as an ISO string in the format yyyy-mm-dd then you can also sort as a string because the lexicographic and date sorting are equal