# Firebase realtime database filter by date child node and update

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a real-time database and one of its collections looks something like this:

```
"VisitorRecords" : {
    "1558098355174" : {
      "CardReturnApprovedBy" : "IXWjlt15qJPkjNDbl4PqG1cT13",
      "CreatedBy" : "IXWjlt15qJPkjNDblqG1cc0T13",
      "DatetimeCreated" : "Fri, 17 May 2019 13:05:55 GMT",
      "Status": 1
    },
    "1558445445664" : {
      "CardReturnApprovedBy" : "",
      "CreatedBy" : "IXWjlt15qJPkjNl4PqG1cc0T13",
      "DatetimeCreated" : "Tue, 21 May 2019 13:30:45 GMT",
      "Status": 1
    }
  }
```

My idea here is to filter all of the visitor records which have their **DatetimeCreated** bigger or equal to DateTime.Now (UTC) and then I want to update the **Status** property to **2**. I want to do that from a firebase function.

What I've found so far is **startAt(), endAt()** helper functions but they don't seem to work in my case. Other option is to iterate all of the records and do a manual check for the date. Then, try to update this specific record using **.update**

I was wondering if there's no more simple and elegant way of doing this.

Comment: What is not exactly working about startAt() and endAt() ? can you post what you have tried ?

Comment: @GastónSaillén For example, if I want them to startAt UTC.now but I have no record equal to UTC now.

Comment: With the format of your DatetimeCreated values you will have a lot of problems to sort them correctly. You should better use a timestamp, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52728669/querying-by-range-in-firebase/52732340#52732340, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216858/firebase-query-by-date-string/38226376#38226376 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52921518/why-doesnt-the-firebase-query-look-like-list/52931580#52931580

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So, as I understand, your suggestion is the same as the one suggested by 'RenaudTarnec' to have my date represented as a timestamp and then use startAt with a value of utc.now converted to a timestamp number?